# Low memory warning with API: ABPersonSetImageData

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, addressbook

I am getting low memory warning after updating some 20 contacts with images. I have placed the code. Can anyone tell what might be the reason?

```
    NSString *imagepath = [[IDLFactory documentsDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",value];

        NSData *dataRef = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagepath]; 
        CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
        [dataRef release];
        dataRef = nil;
        CFErrorRef error;
        ABPersonRemoveImageData(inContact, &error); // <-- clean any image first from ref

        BOOL ret = ABPersonSetImageData(inContact, cfdata, &error);
        if (ret) 
        {
            ret = ABAddressBookSave(inAddressBook, &error);
        } else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not write the image to the person");
        }
        CFRelease(cfdata);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, I think ABPersonRemoveImageData() sometimes is not necessary, because it will fill with new data.

Second, I guess the memory is occupied by autorelease objects. You need to free these autorelease objects by **NSAutoreleasePool**. If you run the whole things on the same run loop, generally iOS will release those autorelease objects at some time.

Comment: - ABPersonRemoveImageData() will remove if there is any image present or else it will return the FALSE as a return value. It will not fill with new data. - I am not using any autorelease objects to use autoreleasePool here. Anyhow i am having autoreleasePool in the method from where I am calling this snippet.